# Counting revolutions of a DC motor with a Photo Interrupter

Tags: programming, motor, sketch

I have a DC motor which is rated at 11 200 RPM.

I would like to count the actual RPM (it seems to be maybe 1500 RPM from what I can tell manually.)

I bought a Photo Interrupter, and have connected it to pin A0. When the beam of the Photo Interrupter is broken, the reading drops to zero.

All seems to work well when using a delay of 100, but as soon as I drop the delay to less than about 50, I get multiple reads.

This is my code:

```
int must_print = 1;
int sensorValue = 0;

//the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  // read the input on analog pin 0:
  sensorValue = analogRead(A0);

  if (sensorValue > 0) 
    {
      if (must_print == 1)
      {
        must_print = 2;
        Serial.println(sensorValue);
      }
    }

  if (sensorValue == 0) {
    must_print = 1;
  }

  delay(100);        // delay in between reads for stability
}
```

At delay(100) the Serial Monitor looks like this for a single interrupt of 10 seconds:

```
354
```

At delay(50) the Serial Monitor looks like this for a single interrupt of 10 seconds:

```
298
312
328
336
349
360
366
371
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use an analog pin with a photointerruptor.  The photointerruptor is a digital device.  Connect it to, preferably, an interrupt pin and use an interrupt to count your revolutions at high speed.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I just read up on the interrupt pins and I see that it's definitely the way to go. I just don't understand how you would write to the Serial Monitor when using an interrupt.

Comment: You wouldn't.  You just count in the interrupt - everything else is done in loop().

Comment: I'm using the following code, but I don't see anything in the Serial Monitor. :
    int pin = 13;
    int tcnt = 0;
    volatile int state = LOW;

    void setup() 
    {
      pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
      attachInterrupt(0, blink, CHANGE);
    }

    void loop()
    {
       Serial.println(tcnt);
       digitalWrite(pin, state);

    }

    void blink()
    {
       tcnt = tcnt + 1;
       state = !state;
  
  
    }

Comment: @DanielGee - You also need to make tcnt `volatile` and initialize Serial with `Serial.begin(9600); `

Comment: It seems that the Interrupt is incredibly sensitive. If I even touch the wire running from the Arduino Pin 2 to the Photo Interrupter the Interrupt fires - multiple times. Have I done something wrong or is this expected?

Comment: @DanielGee - interrupts are sensitive, especially if you have a long cable between sensor and Pin, try adding a small decoupling cap at the microcontroller pin.

Comment: You must set the input pin to be INPUT_PULLUP

Comment: @Majenko - +1, good point